# Difference between equals (LINQ) and == (C#) operators?

Tags: c#, linq

I have been reading **Programming Microsoft LINQ in Microsoft .NET Framework 4**, and now I am understanding the `join` clause in LINQ, but I have a doubt or question respect about its definition; in the book it is defines as:

> You can define equality comparisons only by using a special `equals` keyword that behaves differently from the `==` operator, because the position of the operands is significant. With `equals`, the left key consumes the outer source sequence, and the right key consumes the inner source sequence. The outer source sequence is in scope only on the left side of `equals`, and the inner source sequence is in scope only on the right side.

And there is also a formal definition about this operator:

`join-clause ::= join innerItem in innerSequence on outerKey equals innerKey`

Please, can someone explain me the above concept in other words or by paraphrasing it?

Comment: `outersource join innersource on outerkey equals innerkey`. Essentially, what they're saying is you cannot write the following: `outersource join innersource on innerkey equals outerkey`

Comment: So now what is the semantic differences between the two in an `IEnumerable` context. I am sure this could help with `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 11):

I guess it's because 'equals' in the join doesn't work like == does, and so the language designers decided not to call what it is doing the same thing.

In C#, it is sort of given that a == b is exactly the same as b == a. In the definition of a join, this is not so:

```
var list = from a in ctx.TableA
           join b from ctx.TableB on a.Id equals b.tableAId
```

This, above, is valid.

```
var list = from a in ctx.TableA
           join b from ctx.TableB on b.tableAId equals a.Id
```

This will not compile. What the language spec says is that the 'outer' table (TableA in this case) must be specified first and the inner one (TableB) must be second. I suppose that the language designers thought that this was sufficiently different from the way that == works that it would be a bad idea to use it and they came up with the idea to use 'equals'.

I think I'm probably right, but only the language designers involved will really know the truth.